# Web Page Inspector

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, javafx

I wrote a small JavaFX Application to inspect Javascript within HTML pages. It loads and browses sites, shows the HTML source, shows an overview of the text of a page, provides a simple Javascript terminal, and runs Javscript files from disk. I'm thinking with some careful perusing it can be at least a little shorter and more succinct. How can this implementation be enhanced?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItemBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Browser extends Application {

    private static final String help = ""
        + "dir=function(x){"
        + "rv=\"\";"
        + "Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key){"
        + "rv+=key+\"\\n\";"
        + "});return rv;};"
        + "dir(%s);";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.setVisible(true);
        Menu viewMenu = new Menu("Options");
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(viewMenu);

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine eng = webView.getEngine();
        eng.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    primaryStage.setTitle(eng.getTitle());
                }
            }
        });
        final MenuItem viewContent
            = MenuItemBuilder.create()
            .text("Content")
            .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                showText("Content of " + eng.getTitle(), primaryStage,
                    (String) eng.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerText"));
            })
            .accelerator(
                new KeyCodeCombination(
                    KeyCode.V, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
            .build();
        final MenuItem viewSource
            = MenuItemBuilder.create()
            .text("Source")
            .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                showText("Source of " + eng.getTitle(), primaryStage,
                    (String) eng.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML"));
            })
            .accelerator(
                new KeyCodeCombination(
                    KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
            .build();
        final MenuItem console
            = MenuItemBuilder.create()
            .text("Console")
            .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                console(primaryStage, eng);
            })
            .accelerator(
                new KeyCodeCombination(
                    KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
            .build();
        final MenuItem openScript
            = MenuItemBuilder.create()
            .text("Open Script")
            .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                File file = new FileChooser().showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                if (file != null) {
                    String result;
                    try {
                        result = (String)eng.executeScript(readFile(file.getCanonicalPath(),
                            Charset.defaultCharset()));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        result = ex.getMessage();
                    }
                    alert("Result", "Final Value", "Final Value of Script:", result);
                }
            })
            .accelerator(
                new KeyCodeCombination(
                    KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
            .build();
        viewMenu.getItems().addAll(viewContent, viewSource, console, openScript);

        TextField address = new TextField();
        address.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            String ch = ke.getCharacter();
            switch (ch.getBytes()[0]) {
                case 13:
                    ke.consume();
                    eng.load(address.getText());
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(address);
        root.setCenter(webView);
        root.setBottom(menuBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void showText(String title, Stage primaryStage, String text) {
        TextArea root = new TextArea(text);
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        secondStage.setTitle(title);
        secondStage.setScene(secondScene);
        secondStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        secondStage.show();
    }

    ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();

    private void console(Stage primaryStage, WebEngine eng) {
        final String PROMPT = "> ";
        TextArea root = new TextArea(PROMPT);
        root.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace");
        root.setOnKeyTyped((KeyEvent ke) -> {
            String ch = ke.getCharacter();
            ke.consume();
            switch (ch.getBytes()[0]) {
                case 13:
                    try {
                        if (input.length() == 0 && history.size() > 0) {
                            input = new StringBuilder(history.get(history.size() - 2).substring(PROMPT.length()));
                            break;
                        } else if (input.toString().contains(" ")
                            && input.toString().split(" ")[0].equals("help")) {
                            System.out.println(String.format(help, input.toString().split(" ")[1]));
                            input = new StringBuilder(String.format(help, input.toString().split(" ")[1]));
                        }
                        history.add(PROMPT + input.toString());
                        history.add(eng.executeScript(input.toString()).toString());
                    } catch (Exception jse) {
                        history.add(jse.toString());
                    }
                    input = new StringBuilder();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (input.length() > 0) {
                        input.setLength(input.length() - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    input.append(ch);
                    break;
            }
            root.setText("");
            // while (history.size() > 20) history.remove(0);
            history.stream().forEach((entry) -> {
                root.appendText(entry + "\n");
            });
            root.appendText(PROMPT);
            root.appendText(input.toString());
            root.positionCaret(root.getLength());
        });
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        secondStage.setTitle("Javascript Console");
        secondStage.setScene(secondScene);
        secondStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        secondStage.show();
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
        throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    private void alert(String title, String header, String content, String extra) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(header);
        alert.setContentText(content);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(extra);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        textArea.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        textArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setHgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

        GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
        expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        expContent.add(textArea, 0, 1);

        alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Tip: you can type `help document`, for example; in the console window. This command will be auto-replaced with a short script to output a listing of `document`. When running scripts just remember this program tries to convert and diplay the last statement as a string. You can also press `Enter` at the console to replay the last input. Lastly, I want to present a script that displays links from a given page:

```
var arr = [], l = document.links;

for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {

    arr.push(l[i].href);

};
print = function(item) {
    document.write("<a href=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</a><br>");
    result += item + "\n";
}
result = "";
arr.forEach(print);
result
```

The project is available on [github](https://github.com/seanisko/Browser). Some screenshots:

[image: main]

[image: test output]

[image: source output]

[image: console output]

[image: script output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 13:
```

If you're going to add in hooks to keycodes like that, either

1. Use the `KeyCode` class you were using earlier
2. Make use of java's char to byte casting; use `'\r'`
3. Define the value as a constant `KEYCODE_CARRIAGE_RETURN`
4. Add a comment `// \r carriage return, enter key`.

I'd prefer 1 or 2.

---

I also think it would be handy if these objects

```
    final MenuItem viewContent
        = MenuItemBuilder.create()
        .text("Content")
        .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            showText("Content of " + eng.getTitle(), primaryStage,
                (String) eng.executeScript("document.documentElement.innerText"));
        })
        .accelerator(
            new KeyCodeCombination(
                KeyCode.V, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
        .build();
    final MenuItem viewSource
        = MenuItemBuilder.create()
        .text("Source")
        .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            showText("Source of " + eng.getTitle(), primaryStage,
                (String) eng.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML"));
        })
        .accelerator(
            new KeyCodeCombination(
                KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
        .build();
    final MenuItem console
        = MenuItemBuilder.create()
        .text("Console")
        .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            console(primaryStage, eng);
        })
        .accelerator(
            new KeyCodeCombination(
                KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
        .build();
    final MenuItem openScript
        = MenuItemBuilder.create()
        .text("Open Script")
        .onAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            File file = new FileChooser().showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                String result;
                try {
                    result = (String)eng.executeScript(readFile(file.getCanonicalPath(),
                        Charset.defaultCharset()));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    result = ex.getMessage();
                }
                alert("Result", "Final Value", "Final Value of Script:", result);
            }
        })
        .accelerator(
            new KeyCodeCombination(
                KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN))
        .build();
```

Were created each in their own function. Right now, populating the view is a messy place, and by stowing these elements into separate functions you can keep the menu items and the management of menu items apart.